# CryptImportKey in CryptoAPI accepts hPubKey of 0 to import encrypted session key

Tags: session, cryptography, cryptoapi, encryption

Can anyone explain why the CryptImportKey function accepts an hPubKey of 0 (the decryption key handle), when importing an encrypted session-type key-blob from another computer?

The environment is this:

PC #1: Generates a key exchange key-pair (public/private) in a local key-container (`CryptGenKey` w/ AT_KEYEXCHANGE), then exports the public portion as a PUBLICKEYBLOB and sends it to PC #2

PC #2: Takes the public key-blob from PC #1 and imports it to a local key-container. Creates a session key in the same local key-container. Exports the local key-container session key to a SIMPLEBLOB (`CryptExportKey`), using the public key that was imported from the client's key blob (this is used to encrypt the session key).

PC #1: Takes the encrypted session key-blob from PC #2 and calls `CryptImportKey`, providing the local key container hProv, the key-blob buffer pointer and length, 0 (zero) for hPubKey and flags, and a pointer to an HCRYPTKEY handle.

After doing the above I get a valid handle back, and can call `CryptEncrypt` and `CryptDecrypt` using the handle I got back. Yes, if I specify on CryptImportKey the handle of the key exchange key-pair generated from the first step above on PC #1, that works as well. I just don't understand why a 0 for hPubKey works, it's as if the CryptoAPI "knows" what the private key was to encrypt the data.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think of is that you use this within a session (which has context, thus knows the private key), or that you are not actually encrypting the data. Note that it is actually possible to look up the private key using the modulus as a unique key, but I could not fathom that they would use such a method without telling the user.

PS sorry, I cannot make comments to your question directly (yet), so I posted this because of the long time frame.